# New to coding and having trouble with "identifier "string" is undefined" error

Tags: c++-cli

```
#include "MyForm.h"
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

[STAThread];
void main(array<string^>^ args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    Organizer::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);
}
```

`
I keep getting the error "identifier "string" is undefined"
how can i fix this? im new to coding and have minimal knowledge, any help is appreciated

Comment: Usually it's `std::string`. I'm not sure what you should use in the managed c++ environment. The `main()` function signatur always should look like `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` though.

Comment: C++ and C++-CLI are quite different beasts. That code you posted will not compile with any Standard C++ compiler that I am aware of. I have removed the C++ tag as it doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 1):

The .Net managed [`System::String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) class starts with a capital "S".

You'll also need the namespace `System::` or a `using namespace System;` directive at the top of the file. (Which might already be there, and you just didn't copy it to the web.)

Now, that said: If you're new to coding, please do yourself a favor and don't start with C++/CLI. Either start with C#, or with plain C++. C++/CLI is intended for .Net managed code to interact with unmanaged C/C++ code. It has all the complexities of C#, C++, and a few of its own, and is therefore not a good language to learn with.